# JSP and HTML - Refreshing that doesn't up data the webpage

Tags: html, jsp, refresh

In my web client I have inside an if statement a command like this

```
myList = myBean.getNewList();
```

that references a global List and is displayed in table form in the web page.

How is it that my web page doesn't update the table on screen till I refresh the page again? It seems to refresh by its self straight away after a button is pressed

Comment: If you clear your cache does it update? If so, it's probably the browser caching the page.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. Maybe the JSP page isn't actually refreshing itself :S. If that is the case how can I update the table that list is dependent on?

Answer (score 0):

Where is that code?  In the *.jsp file, or in some backing java action?

Most likely, that code is never called until there is a request made to the server, via a button click which would probably do one of the following (depending on your application):

1. Submitting a form or making some request to the server and building some response object to be rendered by your browser
2. Make some Ajax call to change the innerHtml of one of your DOM elements
3. use jQuery (or some other javascript) to change the innerHTML on the fly with some hard-coded data

Comment: Yeah the 'if' statement is in one form and the table is a different form. if(request.getParameter("RemoveFromCart") != null) { remove from cart in the bean and then get the cart's contents }